# static fields problems in initialization

Tags: java

I have searched the JDK many times, but I can't find where the out field is initialized

such as

```java
public static final InputStream in = null;
public static final PrintStream out = null;
public static final PrintStream err = null;
```

So when are these static fields in the System class initialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [openjdk-11 `java.lang.System`](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/System.java) on line [1968](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/System.java#L1968)

```
setOut0(newPrintStream(fdOut, props.getProperty("sun.stdout.encoding")));
```

which is in `private static void initPhase1()` and that is documented to

> Initialize the system class.  Called after thread initialization.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to first check out FileDescriptor.java then come back and check System.java again more thoroughly. You can easily find these files in the src folder of your java installation.

I copied some code from these files with out as example here but you can easily find the answers for in and err in a very similar way.

from FileDescriptor.java

```
public static final FileDescriptor out = new FileDescriptor(1);
```

from System.java

```
public static void setOut(PrintStream out) {
    checkIO();
    setOut0(out);
private static native void setOut0(PrintStream out);
FileOutputStream fdOut = new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out);
setOut0(newPrintStream(fdOut, props.getProperty("sun.stdout.encoding")));
```

Keep in mind that these lines are not connected, and I didn't copy all the code necessary to answer your question but only some of the most inspiring ones. So read as much as you need from these two java files for a better comprehension.

Also keep in mind that not all java "capabilities" are implemented in java itself i.e.

```
setOut0();
```

Which I haven't find its implementation in java source files cause it's supposed to be implemented by other means.